# Pine Script version 4 limit parameter on strategy.entry doesn't run

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to implement my strategy.
Strategy need to place limit orders (close position at a certain price, calculated by my script before `strategy.entry`).

Here my snippet:

`strategy.entry("Long " + unique_name, long=true, limit=long_take_profit, comment=tostring(long_take_profit, '#.##'), when = window())`

**With this code, backtesting keeps my first position opened forever.**

I've tried to solve in another way placing another limit order with `strategy.exit`

`strategy.exit("TP Long", "Long " + unique_name, limit=long_take_profit)`

**It runs! but...**
I'm not satisfied because I'm looking to implement a pyramiding strategy with multiple entry in same direction. I'd like to place multiple order with specific limit for everyone. Unfortunately, `strategy.exit` seams to ignore `from_entry` parameter (maybe another issue?). Anyway, I'd like to get control of my code and I'd like to know ***why the simpler `strategy.entry` with `limit` parameter doesn't run as expected***

Thanks for your contribution

[UPDATE] This is my full script

```
//@version=4
strategy(title="Cross Checks", pyramiding=5, shorttitle="CC", max_bars_back=200, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=5, initial_capital=100000, calc_on_every_tick=true, calc_on_order_fills=true, process_orders_on_close=true, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.00, slippage = 2, overlay=false)

// Getting inputs
   
window() => true 

fast_length = input(title="Fast Length", type=input.integer, defval=12)
slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", type=input.integer, defval=26)
src = input(title="Source", type=input.source, defval=close)

// Calculating
fast_ema = ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma(src, slow_length)

ema = ema(close, 100)
rsi = rsi(close, 14)
cci = cci(close, 14)

spread = 0.0009  
profit_perc = 0.0100

cross_long = crossover(fast_ema, slow_ma)
check_ema_long = low > ema and ema > ema[1]
check_rsi_long = rsi < 90 and rsi > 40 and rsi > rsi[1]
check_cci_long = cci < 180 and cci > -50 and cci > cci[1]
check_security_long = hist_security[1] > hist_security[2]

cross_short = crossunder(fast_ema, slow_ma)
check_ema_short = high < ema and ema < ema[1]
check_rsi_short = rsi < 60 and rsi > 20 and rsi < rsi[1]
check_cci_short = cci > -180 and cci < 50 and cci < cci[1]

check_spread = spread < profit_perc

condition_entry_long = cross_long and check_rsi_long and check_cci_long and check_ema_long and check_spread
condition_entry_short = cross_short and check_rsi_short and check_cci_short and check_ema_short and check_spread

unique_name = tostring(timenow)

// take profit strategy
long_take_profit = close * (1 + profit_perc - spread)
short_take_profit = close * (1 - profit_perc + spread)

if condition_entry_long
    strategy.entry("Long " + unique_name, long=true, limit=long_take_profit, comment=tostring(long_take_profit, '#.##'), when = window())

if condition_entry_short
    strategy.entry("Short " + unique_name, long=false, limit=short_take_profit, comment=tostring(short_take_profit, '#.##'), when = window())
```

Comment: Without full code hard to guess where is the problem.

Comment: @AndreyD check my update please and thanks for your contribution ;)

Comment: I suggest to add debug plots: `plot(condition_entry_long ? long_take_profit : na, style=plot.style_linebr)` for visualize. Maybe you will can see where the problem is.

Comment: @AndreyD nothing relevant. Consider that if I put `strategy.exit("TP Long", "Long " + unique_name, limit=long_take_profit)` it runs! In this case the problem is that limit effect all opened transaction (opposite direction included!)... **it seems something is not working properly**

Comment: I am having the same issue. My limit orders under strategy.entry are opening way off. Very annoying!